# Printing Implicit Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, string, var, implicit

I have searched for this but I haven't got my answer .So I am here.
okay , so here is the code

```
var contacts = new[] 
{
    new
    {
        Name = " Eugene Zabokritski",
        PhoneNumbers = new[] { "206-555-0108", "425-555-0001" }
    },
    new
    {
        Name = " Hanying Feng",
        PhoneNumbers = new[] { "650-555-0199" }
    }
};
```

I want to print out the Phonenumbers but when I try I get System.String[] instead.
I tried foreach loop as well . So what's the way to print out the Name as well as Phone Number?

Comment: What is the code for printing phone numbers?

Comment: what's the specific result you expect?

Comment: @ZoranHorvat I tried to use 
foreach (var i in contacts)
        Console.WriteLine(i);

and I am getting this 
<Name = Eugene Zabokritski PhoneNumbers = System.String[]>

Comment: @CircleHsiao 
I expect this
<Name = Eugene Zabokritski PhoneNumbers = 206-555-0108 425-555-0001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of string.Join here:

```
foreach(var contact in contacts)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", contact.Name);
   Console.WriteLine("PhoneNumbers: {0}", string.Join(",",contact.PhoneNumbers));
}
```

Comment: Thanks , It Worked .